# What's the easiest way to parse multiple XML files with NSXMLParser?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I have an array with URLs and I have tried just `[myParserObject parse]` for next URL inside of `- (void)parserDidEndDocument: (NSXMLParser *)parser` but it says *NSXMLParser does not support reentrant parsing*.

Is there easy way to parse several XMLs?

Answer (score -2):

I had same requirement while building my app in Swift. I did this by iterating and parsing URL's :

```
var parser = NSXMLParser()

    let url1 = "http://www.test1.xml"
    let url2 = "http://www.test2.xml"
    let url3 = "http://www.test3.xml"
    let url4 = "http://www.test4.xml"        
    let urlArray = [url1 , url2, url3, url4]

    for url in urlArray{
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string: url))!)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
    }
```